# Out of Memory Error - Trying to use Win API to check memory usage in ErrorHandler

Tags: excel, vba, winapi

I have a procedure in Excel VBA that is causing an out of memory error. I'm trying to check memory usage as part of my ErrorHandler as well as take a snapshot of how far along execution has reached when the error is encountered.

I've found the following code that calls the Win API and provides the 'Working Set Size' memory but I also would like to check the Commit Size. Does anyone know what syntax I should use for the Commit Size?

I assume I need to change .WorkingSetSize with something else but I can't find a reference and random tests with things like 'CommitSize' don't work.

Thanks in advance.

```
Declare Function GetCurrentProcessId Lib "kernel32" () As Long

Function GetWorkingSetSize()
Dim objSWbemServices As Object

' Returns the current Excel.Application
' memory usage in MB

Set objSWbemServices = GetObject("winmgmts:")
GetWorkingSetSize = objSWbemServices.Get( _
  "Win32_Process.Handle='" & _
  GetCurrentProcessId & "'").WorkingSetSize / 1024

Set objSWbemServices = Nothing

End Function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
Function GetPctCommittedBytes()

Dim colItems As Variant
Dim objItem As Variant

Set colItems = GetObject("WinMgmts:root/cimv2").ExecQuery("Select * FROM Win32_PerfFormattedData_PerfOS_Memory ")

For Each objItem In colItems
    Debug.Print objItem.PercentCommittedBytesInUse
    Debug.Print objItem.CommittedBytes
Next

GetPctCommittedBytes = objItem.CommittedBytes

End Function
```

H/T to [THIS](http://www.visualbasicscript.com/Script-to-monitor-my-computers-hard-disk-space-cpu-usage-in-and-memory-RAM-usage-in-m61955.aspx) which pointed me in the right direction.  I had to use the object browser to review the available properties for `objItem`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this.  That does return info but I can't yet understand what it's referring to.  Is this giving me The commit size for everything running?  If so, do you know how I just reference excel.exe?

Comment: This is everything running I believe. The commit size for XL is probably not the source of your problem...

Comment: Thanks.  Middle of the night I thought to check the Task Manager Performance tab (I'm in Win7) and this call results in an almost identical number to their Commit size.  Thanks.       I know very little about memory allocation so I'm sure you are right about the XL commit size not being a factor.  At the moment I'm casting around hoping to find something that gives me a clue to the problem.

Comment: No problem. I know very little about this too, but I'm pretty well-versed in VBA, a little bit in WinAPI, and I'm handy enough with the ol' Google to be able to come up with answers like this :).  I say that about the XL commit size only because it's unlikely to help you diagnose the problem. My limited understanding is that it would only be a symptom of some underlying problem(s) in the code. Or at least that would be the first place I started looking. Good luck! And if that has answered your question please consider accepting it or upvoting if it has helped further your understanding.

Comment: I did accept your code as the answer.  Thanks again.  If you know how to check a process specific commit size I would be grateful.

Comment: I bet there's a way to modify that query but that's outside of my area of expertise. I'd have a look [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394597(v=vs.85).aspx) and see if that documentation might point you in the right direction.

Comment: This is great (though a bit above my paygrade at the moment).  I'll work through it and post back questions.  Thanks again.

Comment: Also above my pay grade, but looks promising. If I were you, I'd give it a few tries, and then maybe post a *new* question for more visibility, with all these details someone here will likely be able to  get you going.

Answer (score 0):

To find out how much memory is available to VBA copy/paste the code below and call `availableMemoryInMB()`

```
Function allocateMB(intNumMB As Integer) As Boolean
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim a As Variant
    ReDim a(intNumMB, 256, 256) As Variant 'intNumMB x 256 x 256 x 16 bytes = intNumMB MB
    allocateMB = (Err.Number = 0)
    Err.Clear
    Erase a
End Function

Function availableMemoryInMB() As Integer
    Dim intLow As Integer, intHigh As Integer, intTest As Integer
    intTest = 1: intHigh = 0
    Do
        If allocateMB(intTest) Then
            intLow = intTest
            If intHigh = 0 Then
                intTest = intTest * 2
            Else
                intTest = (intLow + intHigh) / 2
            End If
        Else
            intHigh = intTest
            intTest = (intLow + intHigh) / 2
        End If
    Loop Until intHigh - intLow <= 1 And intHigh > 0
    availableMemoryInMB = intLow
End Function
```

Execution of the code takes 2-20 seconds.